# Reveal part of image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to try and implement an interactive effect using jquery or javascript.  The idea is to have a large background image with different words about a business.  This background image will be darkened out but the mouse hover will act like a light to reveal a defined area around the mouse cursor.

I'm not sure if i'm on the right track but my general idea is to have a background image with a fully opaque image infront of it with its opacity set to 1.  On mousehover, the opacity of the image will change within a defined radius of the mouse hover.

Can anyone tell me how a good way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Please show us some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/ow4yxov6/).

The trick behind it is [`rem`](https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $magic = $(".magic"),
    magicWHalf = $magic.width() / 2;
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    $magic.css({
      "left": e.pageX - magicWHalf,
      "top": e.pageY - magicWHalf
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scene {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1d1f20;
  padding: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.magic {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10rem);
  left: calc(50% - 10rem);
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url("http://beautifulphotos.atguru.in/beautifulimages/30-beautiful-peacocks/beautiful-peacocks-11.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scene">
  <h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
  <div class="magic"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad, I could help. It is a good practice to "Accept" and "Upvote"(if possible) the helpful answer as it helps everyone who visits this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer solution would be to do it in simple CSS, without adding any javascript, so you can just add a class and do it with all your images, something like:

```
.arrow:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works nicely but it reveals the whole image.  I think javascript may be needed to reveal a radius of say, 200px by 200px around the mouse cursor

Comment: .arrow:hover{
 opacity: 0.5;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}